# Terraform doesn't seem to iterate on my list when invoked from a module

Tags: terraform

I have a simple module that's something like this:

```
module "EncryptionKeys" {
  source                 = "../../../../Modules/KeyGenerator"
  item_list              = ["${module.static_variables.item_list}"]
  account_id             = "${module.static_variables.account_id}"
  key_alias_suffix       = "a-suffix"
  key_administrator_role = "${data.aws_iam_role.admins.name}"
  key_user_suffix        = "some-other-suffix"
}
```

Here is the key resource within the module:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  count               = "${length(var.item_list)}"
  description         = "${var.description}"
  policy             = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.key_document.json}"
  enable_key_rotation = "${var.enable_key_rotation}"
}
```

The module itself is making an AWS IAM role/policy with the following statement:

```
statement {
  sid = "Allow use of the key for users"
  effect = "Allow"
  principals {
    identifiers = 
["arn:aws:iam::${var.account_id}:role/${var.key_administrator_role}", "${element(split(".",var.item_list[count.index]),0)}-${var.key_user_suffix}"]
    type = "AWS"
}
actions = [
  "kms:Encrypt",
  "kms:Decrypt",
  "kms:ReEncrypt*",
  "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
  "kms:DescribeKey"
]
resources = ["*"]
 }
```

The problem? When I view the successful terraform plan, item_list is parsed correctly according to the element, but it's only ever the same value. i.e. if I have item_list defined as:

```
item_list = ["a.blah", "b.foo", "c.bar", "d.foobar"]
```

there will be four instances of the relevant resources, the correct split will occur on the ".", but all will be named for "a".

```
"{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Id": "key=consolepolicy-3",
 "Statement": [
 {
  "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "kms:*",
  "Resource": "*",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Admins"
  }
},
{
  "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources for admin",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "kms:RevokeGrant",
    "kms:ListGrants",
    "kms:CreateGrant"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Admins"
  },
  "Condition": {
    "Bool": {
      "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
    }
  }
},
{
  "Sid": "Allow use of the key for users",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "kms:ReEncrypt*",
    "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
    "kms:Encrypt",
    "kms:DescribeKey",
    "kms:Decrypt"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "a-stg-role",
      "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Admins"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "Sid": "Allow attachment of persistent resources for users",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "kms:RevokeGrant",
    "kms:ListGrants",
    "kms:CreateGrant"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "a-stg-role",
      "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/Admins"
    ]
  },
  "Condition": {
    "Bool": {
      "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": "true"
    }
  }
}
]
}"
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong with count/count.index here? Why won't it loop item_list, and why does it always seem to get the same value?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, second, how the module `static_variables` looks?

Comment: @BMW Please let me know what is unclear about my question and I will do my best to clarify. Static variables is just a means of passing in variables to this and other modules, it only contains outputs like: output "foo" { default = "bar" }

Comment: I've added the plan output above to show how it looks - the computations are being done on the strings, but every instance of the policy has the same "a-stg-role" value. The list contains a, b, c, d, but instead, there are four a-stg-role policies - the list is not iterated. Why?

Comment: Where do you specify the count variable? It always needs to be initialized to e.g. `count = "${length(item_list)}"`, otherwise count.index will never iterate

Comment: @Blokje5 Thanks - I've added the key resource that makes use of that data object in the module. It is where count is set to length of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the count on the resource key, but that does not mean it is available for your `aws_iam_policy_document`.

Try to include the count in the `aws_iam_policy_document`, e.g.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "key_document" {
  count = "${length(var.item_list)}"

  # rest of template ....
}
```

Then reference the policy list from the key resource using the count in the key resource: `policy = "${element(data.aws_iam_policy_document.key_document.*.json, count.index)}"`

Comment: Thanks for this, this is exactly it. I misunderstood the scoping of this variable.